# Do I need any additional configuration for express to use https?

Tags: ssl, express

If I got a signed certificate from [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/) and baked it into my nginx web server, does that mean I still need to configure express.js to use https?

As in nginx serves me a secure webpage, and I see the https lock on the top left, but do I need to do any extra configuration with express at all??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No node/express does not need to handle ssl - you can have a separate service for node/express and have nginx act as a reverse proxy and do ssl offloading.

Under this configuration, browsers will first hit your nginx web server over HTTPS, nginx will handle the ssl decryption and forward the decrypted HTTP request to your node process. 
Your node process doesn't have to know HTTPS is happening at all.

Digital Ocean really has the best docs for setting this up on linux with systemd.

- The [first link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-using-systemd-and-nginx) is a clear tutorial on setting up a an nginx reverse proxy to node
- The [second link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins)  shows configuring SSL in nginx w/ a simple reverse proxy (in this specific example - its not a node server on the receiving end but the concepts are the same) to accomplish the SSL termination

Comment: ahhhh Okay I see, thank you very much. I have already followed those tutorials in the past I was just wondering if express needed some extra information and I stumbled upon the [https module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) so I thought that I needed to configure express to send or receive https requests explicitly. I see now that nginx takes care of that for me. Thanks for answering my question this makes more sense now.